# Error: "Suite Integration Toolkit Executable has stopped working" during VS2010 installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

After uninstallation of VS2012 and installing back Visual Studio 2010 C# Express I was getting strange warning:

> 2008 is not a valid number

so I decided to reinstall VS2010, but I couldn't uninstall it. I was getting error:

> Suite Integration Toolkit Executable has stopped working.

I managed to uninstall VS2010 with VS2010 Uninstall Tool, but now I want to install Visual Studio 2010 C# Express back. I'm getting `Suite Integration Toolkit[...]` error again when I try to install it using web installer. Could you help me resolve my problem?

[image: error message]

And I've got Tablet PC Components function disabled in Control Panel / Programs and Utilites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff` in cmd.exe and then reboot solved problem. When installation is finished you can use: `bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOn`.